# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage error for creating a relationship

Tags: c#, generics, neo4jclient

So I have a class that describes the Relationship like so:

```
public class GraphRelationship<TObject> : Relationship<RelationshipObject>, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<TObject>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<TObject>
    {
        string RelationshipName;

        public GraphRelationship(string RelationshipName, NodeReference targetNode, RelationshipObject relationshipTypeObject)
            : base(targetNode, relationshipTypeObject)
        {
            this.RelationshipName = RelationshipName;
        }

        public override string RelationshipTypeKey
        {
            get { return RelationshipName; }
        }
    }
```

Now I have a method that I want to use to create an instance of the above mentioned class, but I get this `The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage` error.

Here is the method:

```
public RelationshipReference CreateObjectRelationship(string relationshipType, string parentObjectId, string childObjectId, RelationshipObject relationshipProperties)
{
    RelationshipReference relationshipReference = 0;

    NodeReference parentNodeReference = GetObjectReference(parentObjectId);
    NodeReference childNodeReference = GetObjectReference(childObjectId);

    //This is where the error is
    relationshipReference = GraphConnection.CreateRelationship(parentNodeReference, new GraphRelationship<RelationshipObject>(relationshipType, childNodeReference, relationshipProperties));

    return relationshipReference;
}
```

[image]

Im sure this is a trivial problem, but how would i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it, my `NodeReferences` needed to be of Type `<TObject>`

`NodeReference<TObject> parentObjectReference = GetObjectReference(Id);`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to make a generic implementation of a generic relationship, with an obsolete part of the Neo4jClient API.

Use Cypher. ;)

Comment: which parts of API are obsolete, we are using the client quite extensively.

Comment: Basically anything that doesn't have "Cypher" in the code path somewhere. That's inline with the direction of Neo4j itself.

I'll be spending a few days at the Neo offices in San Fran this week with other driver authors, and will take the time then to publish better guidance around this.